# Unable to stop the recursion at certain condition

Tags: java, recursion

I am doing string (i.e. `char array`) processing with recursion. In my `recursion tree`, string located at `child` has length less than 1 w.r.t its `parent` and all children at the same height have same length of string but different characters. I want to stop the recursion whenever new `string` length is greater than or equal to old string length, but i am unable to insert this condition in between recursion. Using `System.exit(0)` terminates my complete program, which i don't want. Below is my code snippet-

```
private static void getMinLen(char[] oldStr) {
    int len = oldStr.length;

    /*
     * This terminates the whole program, using break in place of
     * System.exit(0) is not effective
     */
    if (len < 2)
        System.exit(0);

    char[] newStr = new char[len - 1];

    for (int i = 0; i < len - 1; i++) {
        /*
         * Every character is matched with its next character and a new char
         * array is created having length (len-1)
         */
        getMinLen(newStr);
    }
}
```

Actually when i put `System.out.println("length=" + len);` in the 3rd line. First it prints the length in decreasing order but then length increases, decreases because of recursion. I mean the console shows the following-

```
length=6
length=5
length=4
length=3
length=2
length=1
length=3
length=3
length=2
length=1
length=4
length=3
length=2
length=1
```

I simply want to stop my recursion whenever new length becomes greater than or equal to old length.

Comment: for what purpose you are using `for` loop without using its incremental variable? Just to run the method `getMinLen` with exactly same arguments?

Comment: But, what exactly do you want your method to do? What should be the output if the input is `new char[]{'h', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o'}`?

Comment: Your loop calls `getMinLen` with a series of increasing arguments. This would explain the down-and-up pattern of output. It has nothing to do with breaking or returning from the recursive function. It is that you are duplicating the recursive logic with an iterative loop.

Comment: @AlexStybaev: I haven't write the complete code here. The `for` loop checks a character with it's next character. Then some conditions check the character. this will create a new char array of length `n-1` containing different characters.

Answer (score 1):

In every call to `getMinLen(oldStr)` where the stop condition is not satisfied, you call `getMinLen(newStr)` several times (in fact as many times as there are elements in `newStr`). It is not clear from your question or your first comment whether this is intentional. (The fact that your `newStr` has as many elements as your loop has iterations may suggest it is not.)

If this is not intentional, just move the recursive call one line down, i.e. behind the closing `}` of the loop.

If it is intentional, the problem may be that you have not understood how recursion works. The fact that the stop condition is fulfilled somewhere is not recorded globally and only relevant for the single call in which the stop condition is fulfilled. This point was itself reached by a recursive call `getMinLen`'s `for` loop (unless you start with a very short string), and that (outer) `for` loop continues to execute all subsequent  calls to `getMinLen`--why should it stop? To make it stop, a global boolean variable would help, but be very inelegant. Alternatively, you could make the function return a boolean value and check before each recursive call whether a previous one returned `true`. You may also, however, reconsider whether a recursive approach is really the most suitable for the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Just replace `System.exit(0);` by `return;` at the line you want to exit your method

Comment: He will still have "increases" after the range was decreased.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `return`.

```
if (len < 2)
    return;
```

Comment: He will still have "increases" after the range was decreased.

Comment: Note that if `len < 2`, the recursive loop won't enter.

Comment: @adarshr: i used `return` also. but still i am unable to control the recusion. In my question i put the console output also (just for debugging). When the `length` became 1 at the first time, i just need to stop the recursion there. after that point new `length` becomes greater than old `length`. How can i store the old `length` so that i can compare it with new `length`?

Answer (score 0):

Note that `break` does only "break" loops or switch statements. To leave a method you have to reach the return statement or end of the method (which acts as an implicit return statement in case the return type is `void`).

Note that your method does the following:

Assume the initial length is 4:

```
1. create a new array of length 3 (4-1)
2. call the method recursively 3 times with an array of length 3
3. each new call creates an array of length 2 (3-1)
4. call the method recursively again, now 2 times and with an array of length 2
5. each new call creates an array of length 1 (2-1)
6. call the method recursively again, now once and with an array of length 1
7. each new call creates an array of length 0 (1-1)
8. those methods won't enter the loop since the condition now is `i < 0`, which is false with `i = 0`
```

Thus, when printing each length, I'd expect the following output

```
4   //initial call
3   //first iteration of step 2
2   //first iteration of step 4
1   //only iteration of step 6 
2   //second iteration of step 4
1
3   //second iteration of step 2
2   
1   
2   
1
3   //third iteration of step 2
2   
1   
2   
1
```

If you just want one iteration and then stop, why did you put the loop in there?

Comment: What i am trying to achieve is that i am checking a character with it's next character of a char array using `for` loop. after that a new char array is created inside the same `for` loop (i haven't write down that code here). This newly created char array has length `n-1` which contains different characters. Now method `getMinLen` is called with this array.